# Can't get Spannable quite right

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I'm trying to assemble a long bit of text (from several different pieces of data) as the contents of a `TextView`.

I'd like each line to have the following structure:

> {piece 1} | {piece 2}

I'd like each "{piece 1} | " to be a light gray color.
I'd like each "{piece 2}" to be a dark gray color.

I have defined both of these colors.

I'd like the entire label to be a custom font that I've added to my app.

Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
// regularTf is a Typeface created from a font added to this app
mItemCodesLabel.setTypeface(regularTf);
SpannableStringBuilder builder  = new SpannableStringBuilder();
ForegroundColorSpan ltGraySpan  = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.light_gray);
ForegroundColorSpan dkGraySpan  = new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.dark_gray);
int index                       = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < codes.size(); i = i + 1) {
    ParseObject code            = codes.get(i);
    String value                = code.getString("value") + " | ";
    if (i > 0) {
        builder.append("\n");
        index                   = index + 1;
    }
    builder.append(value);
    builder.setSpan(ltGraySpan, index, index + value.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    index                       = index + value.length();
    String loc                  = code.getString("location");
    builder.append(loc);
    builder.setSpan(dkGraySpan, index, index + loc.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    index                       = index + loc.length();
}
mItemCodesLabel.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

The text color for this label is set to `R.color.dark_gray` in my layout file.

The results that I'm seeing are somewhat confusing. I have two codes for an item, and the `TextView` looks like this:

> {code 1 piece 1} | {code 1 piece 2}
>   {code 2 piece 1} | {code 2 piece 2}

"{code 1 piece 1} | " is dark gray. The rest is light gray.

Based on several tutorials I've read on this topic, I don't see anything wrong with my code, but I'll admit that the whole "Spannable" topic still confuses me some. I'm coming from iOS, and `Spannable` seems a lot like `NSAttributedString`, but it seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: We cannot use the same instance of `Span` to mark several parts of the text. Whenever `setSpan()` is called by passing a `Span` instance, the previous span marked by that instance is cleared. I think, by knowing this fact you can overcome the problem. If not reply me, I will post the answer.

Comment: @DurgadassS Yes, this did fix my problem. I had actually come across this information prior to your post from another answer on here as well as trial-and-error. From what I remember, however, I could never find this information in the documentation itself. Would you put your comment into an answer so I can accept it so that this information is easier to find in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot use the same instance of `Span` to mark several parts of the text. Whenever `setSpan()` is called by passing a `Span` instance, the previous span marked by that instance is cleared. I think, by knowing this fact you could solve the problem.